How to Filter Documents Based on Multiple Conditions Using Algolia (Visibility and User-Specific Rules)
I am building an application where I need to display documents based on multiple conditions related to visibility and user relationships. Here’s the logic I want to implement:

Show all documents where visibility is "public".
Show all documents where createdBy is the current user (no matter the visibility).
Show documents where: visibility is "followers"
createdBy is a user that the current user follows.

I initially tried to implement this directly using Firestore, but ran into limitations with full-text search and Firestore’s inability to evaluate follower relationships dynamically within security rules.
What I've Tried with Algolia:
I switched to using Algolia to handle this, and I set up the filters as follows:
filters: 'visibility:"public" OR createdBy:"currentUserId" OR (visibility:"followers" AND (createdBy:"followingUserId"))'

However, this results in the error:

ApiError: filters: filter (X AND Y) OR Z is not allowed, only (X OR Y)
AND Z is allowed

My Question:
Is there a way to structure these filters correctly in Algolia to achieve the desired behavior given the limitation

(X AND Y) OR Z is not allowed, only (X OR Y) AND Z is allowed

?
If this approach is not suitable, what is the recommended method for handling this type of visibility filtering in a scalable and efficient manner using Algolia or any other approach compatible with Firestore?
Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

can you maybe convrt it to the format that they ask. that is the product of sums format. something liek filters: '(visibility:"followers" OR visibility:"public" OR createdBy:"currentUserId") AND (createdBy:"followingUserId" OR visibility:"public" OR createdBy:"currentUserId")' 

Thanks for your reply, but same error. It seem that's not support by Algolia, i switched to client side filter for this...

i see. i once came across this exact scenario and thought it would work. docs
